# What is the difference between COM Service EXE and COM EXE?

Tags: c++, com

What is the difference between COM Service EXE and COM EXE ?

If I've understood the meaning of Service EXE is that I can run a windows service which performs some actions in background or for sharing COMs with some launched applications. But, in this case what's the difference between the running of a Service EXE and an EXE ? Thread management, maybe?

Comment: Same difference as between a non-COM service vs desktop EXE.  You have the source code for CAtlServiceModule and CAtlExeModule on your machine, have a look-see at vc/atlmfc/include/atlbase.h